# python in the case of not calling win32com to excel to pdf

Tags: python, excel, pdf, apache-poi

In the use of python to excel files into pdf, almost always use to win32com, call the interface of the excel application, but how to do the conversion without using the excel application?

---

For example.
I now have two files: example0.doc, example1.docx.

I would like to convert these two files into a pdf file.
For example: example0.pdf, example1.pdf

When I am on windows platform, what I may do is to call the system API .
For example:

```py
import os
import win32com.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

inputFile = os.path.abspath("example0.doc")
outputFile = os.path.abspath("example0.pdf")
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(inputFile)
doc.SaveAs(outputFile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

However, this way depends on the system and I don't want to do this. I would like to find a way to convert the files directly.
The reason for this is that with multiple threads/multiple processes, more problems arise.

I have tried the following programs.

- Using apache poi via jpype, but it failed

Currently looking for a solution

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have used this program at the same time and it gave me inspiration. https://github.com/youngrok/poi4py

Comment: This problem will still occur with python 3.9.5